# ODBC Source From SQL 2014 Error 0xc0014009

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I read the threads and googled before posting. Trying to run job from SSIS integration services catalogs. Trying to connect to a AS400 via OBDC driver via SQL SSIS

Works on Visual studio but fails on sql server.

On Windows 2012 R2, SQL server 2014

[image]

I set settings, DelayedValidation: True and all 32bit
[image]

[image]

I also made sure I have ODBC drivers installed on server.

**I believe it's permission related but need some guidance on what to change/check**

Comment: Can you test that the ODBC driver can connect to the ASA400. You could do this in ODBC Data Source Administrator (32-bit). Add a new connection and then click the Test button.

Comment: Also, why are you using 32-bit?

Comment: @RichardCL For some reason I change the setting in debug. Also I heard that excel operations need 32bit

Comment: Have you installed the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable, or the 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components on the server which is running the IS package?

Comment: Do the necessary DSNs exist on the SQL Server that the job is running on?   Are they SYSTEM DSNs and not USER DSNs?

Comment: @TabAlleman how do I tell and how do i set it up

Comment: @RichardCL I have Microsoft office 2010 standard installed.

Comment: I couldn't get 2010 to work with SSIS. Try 2007. See 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

Comment: @RichardCL Installed suggested extension did not make a difference.

Comment: You may have more luck using the IBM DBO driver for AS/400.

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-odbc-data-source-administrator#1TC=windows-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing AS400 iseries driver.

Contact your IT department it **isn't** available online.

This fixed the 0xc0014009 error